# jQuery ajax redirecting instead of ajaxing

Tags: jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, icheck

I have a jquery script that validates my form using bootstrapvalidator  (http://bootstrapvalidator.com/)
and then if the validation is a success (checkbox checked, not empty etc.) It makes an ajax call.

Problem is when I try to implement it with ICheck plugin (http://fronteed.com/iCheck/)

Instead of doing the ajax request to the page "proceed.php" it redirects me to it (which is a php page with a json call).

So basically when I try to implement my ajax call with the Icheck plugin it redirects instead of doing the ajax (kind of loosing the purpose of ajax here!)

I am a rookie with jQuery and I'm pretty sure it's a simple syntax error so any help would be appreciated.

The website can be tested here: http://entendu.x10.mx

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("form")
        .bootstrapValidator({




        message: 'Pas valide',
        feedbackIcons: {
            valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
            invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
            validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
        },
        submitButtons: 'button[type="submit"]',

        fields: {
            nom: {
                message: 'Votre nom est invalide',
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'Le champ est obligatoire'
                    },
                    stringLength: {
                        min: 1,
                        max: 60,
                        message: 'Le champ doit être compris entre 6 et 60 caractères'
                    },
                    regexp: {
                        regexp: /^[a-zA-Z]*$/,
                        message: 'Le champ ne doit comporter que des lettres'
                    }
                }
            },
            prenom: {
                message: 'Votre prénom est invalide',
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'Le champ est obligatoire'
                    },
                    stringLength: {
                        min: 1,
                        max: 60,
                        message: 'Le champ doit être compris entre 6 et 60 caractères'
                    },
                    regexp: {
                        regexp: /^[a-zA-Z]*$/,
                        message: 'Le champ ne doit comporter que des lettres'
                    }
                }
            },
             matricule: {
                validators: {
                     notEmpty: {
                        message: 'Le champ est obligatoire'
                    },
                     integer: {
                       message: 'Votre matricule doit être composé de chiffres uniquement'
                   }                }
            },

            "date-dispo-from":{
                validators: {

                     notEmpty: {
                        message: 'Le champ est obligatoire'
                    },

                     date: {
                       message: 'La date doit être valide',
                       format: 'YYYY-MM-DD',
                       separator: '-'
                   }                
                 }
            },
             "date-dispo-to":{
                validators: {

                     notEmpty: {
                        message: 'Le champ est obligatoire'
                    },


                     date: {
                       message: 'La date doit être valide',
                       format: 'YYYY-MM-DD',
                       separator: '-'
                   }                
                 }
            },
             "dispo-travail-jours": {
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'Le champ est obligatoire'
                    },
                    integer: {
                        message: 'Le nombre doit être situé entre 0 et 20 jours'
                    }
                }

            },
            "check_date[]": {
                validators: {
                        choice: {
                             min: 8,
                             message: 'Veuillez sélectionner au minimum 8 jours. (1 fin de semaine SUR 2 et 1 jour par semaine)'
                    }
                }

            }

        }
    })
    .find('input[type="checkbox"]')
            // Init iCheck elements
            .iCheck({
                checkboxClass: 'icheckbox_flat-blue',
                radioClass: 'iradio_flat-blue'
            })
            // Called when the radios/checkboxes are changed
            .on('ifChanged', function(e) {
                // Get the field name
                var field = $(this).attr('name');
                $('form').bootstrapValidator('revalidateField', field);
            })
        .on('success.form.bv', function(e) {
            // Prevent form submission
            e.preventDefault();

            // Get the form instance
            var $form = $(e.target);

            // Get the BootstrapValidator instance
            var bv = $form.data('bootstrapValidator');

            // Use Ajax to submit form data
            var postData = $('form').serialize();

        $.ajax(
        {
            url : 'process.php',
            type: "POST",
            data : postData,
            dataType: 'json',

            success:function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) 
            {
                    alert(postData);

                $("#result").show('slow');

            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) 
            {
                //if fails      
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I did experience the exact same problem when sending a form through AJAX.

<del>Try isolating the form's DOM element and removing the action attribute.</del>

## My Fix

```
<!-- Fig. A - The Form -->
<form action="do.php" method="POST" onsubmit="validate()">
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Assuming a normal form as above, the onsubmit attribute calls a function and interprets `true` as 'do the submission [navigate to *do.php*, which isn't what we want]' or `false` 'do nothing [what we really want]'

Assuming that you've created a `new XHTTPRequest` and set the options appropriately already (jQuery would likely be doing that for you.) this function invokes that transmission and stops your window from navigating.

```
// Fig. B - The Javascript
function validate () {
    // Invoke the xhr's transmission in a timeout. Refer to your jQuery manual :)
    setTimeout(function () { xhr.send(); }, 1);
    return false; // This will cause the page to stop navigating.
}
```

Since AJAX is  typically used asynchronously, this shouldn't require you to change your code very much as your xhr was continuing your procedure in a different 'thread' or callback anyway.  This is what did the trick for me.  I know you're kind of hybridizing two support libraries too so I hope this is attainable for you.

Comment: No sorry this isn't helping... Doesn't change my problem. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @francoboy7 have you set a break on the forms onsubmit handler?  I've found that initiating an http request from within the onsubmit causes it to redirect the main window to the forms action attribute even if the main onsubmit thread returns false.  The only work around for me was setting action to a null string before sending my xhr.

Comment: Could you write me an example i'm not quite sure to understand as english isn't my first language. Thanks